# When outputting, it is found that currentId is not 10000 as expected. Why? How to correct it

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

This code I saw by chance.
The code is roughly as follows.

```
    public class Question2
    {
        public void Run()
        {
            List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            {
                tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    GetNextId();
                }));
            }
            Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
            
            Console.WriteLine("currentId=" + GetCurrentId());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private int currentId;
        public int GetNextId()
        {
            currentId++;
            return currentId;
        }

        public int GetCurrentId()
        {
            return currentId;
        }
    }
```

I'dont know why result is not 10000? Can somebody tell me why and how to correct it.

Comment: _the code is roughly as follows_?! What is the result when you run the code you posted?

Comment: the result is random, i hope the result is 10000

Comment: https://onlinegdb.com/HyQOpuKPO

Comment: @鍾曜謙 because you start your loop at 1 in the link but 0 in the question

Comment: thanks to answer ,i will keep to the study

Comment: @鍾曜謙 make sure you upvote and **accept*" (checkmark) the answer below since it solved your problem

Comment: For question of the format "My multithreaded program is not behaving as expected", the answer is almost always "your program is not threadsafe". Using multiple threads without understanding the hazards can very easily result in serious bugs that are difficult to reproduce.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just discoverd the topic of thread safety! `currentId++` translates to

1. read the value of currentId from memory
2. increment this value by one
3. write this new value back to memory

Now imagine your loop goes only until i < 3. The first thread is at step 1 and reads the value 0. Before it goes on to step 2, the second thread is at step 1 and also reads 0. Now both threas go to step 3, the will write both 1 into memory. Now the third thread starts and will read 1 from memory, will increment it to 2 and writes it into memory. Now you have 2 instead of the expected value 3.

To fix this, you can use [`Interlocked.Increment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked.increment?view=net-5.0):

```
    private int currentId;
    public int GetNextId()
    {
        return Interlocked.Increment(ref currentId);          
    }
```

But beware, that depending on your use case, you might still get similar problems when you use the return value of `GetNextId()`.

Comment: thank you answer for me,but the result is 9999 after I execute, not 10000.

Comment: What is the value of 0 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 ... 9999 times?

Comment: @鍾曜謙 For me, it works: https://dotnetfiddle.net/VUqnXo

Comment: OP is starting their loop at `1` in the link they provide with the updated code instead of the `0` from the original question.. Of course it's off by 1. IMO learn to use a debugger and pay attention to details *before* trying to learn how to write concurrent/multithreaded code. You'll thank yourself one day

Answer (score 1):

```
currentId++;
```

In a single threaded program, the sequence of events looks like this.

1. Thread reads value of currentId (say, 999).
2. Thread increments value and writes to currentId. Value of currentId is now 1000.

In your multi-threaded program, the sequence of events may look more like this.

1. Thread 1 reads value of currentId (say, 999).
2. Thread 2 reads value of currentId (also, 999).
3. Thread 3 reads value of currentId (also, 999).
4. Thread 2 increments value and writes to currentId. Value of currentId is now 1000.
5. Thread 3 increments value and writes to currentId. Value of currentId is now 1000.
6. Thread 1 increments value and writes to currentId. Value of currentId is now 1000.

So the the value of currentId has been incremented three times but the value is 1000.

One solution to this problem is to use the lock keyword. Using the lock keyword ensures that only one thread has access to a piece of code at one time.

```
    private int currentId;

    private object _object = new object();

    public int GetNextId() {
        lock (_object) {
            currentId++;
            return currentId;
        }
    }
```

The sequence of events now looks like this.

1. Thread 1 gets access to the lock(_object).
2. Thread 1 reads value of currentId (say, 999).
3. Thread 2 requests access to the lock(_object) but is forced to wait until thread 1 releases the lock.
4. Thread 3 requests access to the lock(_object). Request is queued behind thread 2's request.
5. Thread 1 increments value and writes to currentId. Value of currentId is now 1000.
6. Thread 1 releases the lock(_object).
7. Thread 2 gets access to the lock(_object).
8. Thread 2 reads value of currentId (now, 1000).
9. Thread 2 increments value and writes to currentId. Value of currentId is now 1001.
10. Thread 2 releases the lock(_object).
11. Thread 3 gets access to the lock(_object).
12. Thread 3 reads value of currentId (now, 1001).
13. Thread 3 increments value and writes to currentId. Value of currentId is now 1002.
14. Thread 3 releases the lock(_object).

Note that the result will still be 9999 if the initial value is zero and you increment it 9999 times.

Comment: The thing about `lock` is that it's infectious. That is to say that once you use it to guard a field, all accesses of that field should really be wrapped in lock as well. Your implementation has a bug. It can return the value double (or more) incremented if another thread calls the method after the lock but before the return. So your implementation of GetNextId should extend the lock the entire method. Interlocked.Increment on the other hand is atomic, doesn't lock and can return the updated value all in one go. For such a simple case, I'd personally prefer Interlocked

Comment: That or the method could be `lock(_object) return ++currentId` which would at least return the value it was incremented to and keep all accesses within the lock

Comment: @JonasH Thanks for the note. I think you are correct. Code updated.